# Где объявляют переменную?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю игру на движке Unity3d и дошел до страшного...скриптов.

В общем, создавая примитивный FPS контроллер, застрял в самом начале.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FPS_Player_Controler : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 2f;
    CharacterController player;

    float moveFB;
    float moveLR;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        player = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        moveFB = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * speed;
        moveLR = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * speed;

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveLR, moveFB, 0);
        movement = transform.rotation * movement;
        Player.move (movement * time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Да, я знаю что можно просто качать заготовки. Но в любом случае придётся что-то делать ручками.

Как он должен выглядеть правильно?

Comment: а что не так сейчас?

Comment: Ну, объкт не двигается. а проверка говорит что я не объявил переменную

Comment: `проверка говорит что я не объявил переменную` - правильно... потому что `player`, а не `Player`

Comment: Поправил... И...    Error CS1061: "UnityEngine.CharacterController" не содержит определение для "move". Не удалось найти метод  расширения "move", принимающий первый аргумент типа "UnityEngine.CharacterController"  (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?) (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)

Error CS0103: Имя "time" отсутствует в текущем контексте (CS0103) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: Правильно. ... потому что `Move` и `Time`

Comment: Спасибо... Грамматика у меня походу на обе ноги хромает... ЗАРАБОТАЛО! Мой самый первый код! Правда не так как ожидалось. Но работает!

Comment: И так вся проблема была в грамматике... Я не знаю как называются эти термины. Но, думаю со временем вникну. Придётся.
Осталось понять что значат эти строчки.
И может тогда персонаж будет двигаться как надо. Но, покрайне мере он начал двигаться.

Comment: это не грамматика. Просто C#, как и все C-подобные - чувствителен к регистру и различает большие и маленькие буквы. Имена Test, test, TEST - это разные имена.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/153188)

Comment: @Monk это и есть что-то типа ответа...на свой собственный вопрос.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/153188)

Comment: @tCode еще один.... вы хоть немного смотрите на вопрос и ответ и что тут происходит, а не слепо жмакайте кнопАчки))